# How to convert a NumericVector to RcppParallel::RVector<float> or a NumericMatrix to RcppParallel::RMatrix<float>?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

In a parallel code with Rcpp, I convert a NumericVector variable to `RcppParallel::RVector<double>`. I also convert a NumericMatrix variable to `RcppParallel::RMatrix<double>`.

To speed up the code, I would like to use float variables instead of double. Hence, I would like to convert a NumericVector variable to something like `RcppParallel::RVector<float>` and a NumericMatrix variable to something like `RcppParallel::RMatrix<float>`.

Is it possible? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: Because R itself only knows `double` you have to cast element by element,

Comment: And be careful doing it is of course a lossy conversion from larger to smaller range / resolution just how not all int64_t values fit into an int (that is halt the size, just like float to double).

Comment: For your information, I have been able to convert an IntegerMatrix to a  RcppParallel::RMatrix<int>. However, I have not been able to convert a LogicalMatrix to a  RcppParallel::RMatrix<bool>.